# ttwMusicPlayer action on play button

Tags: jquery, audio-player

I'm using [ttwMusicPlayer](http://www.codebasehero.com/2011/06/html-music-player/) on my site. 
It's usage is pretty simple.

```
<div id='mainPlayer'></div>
```

in html
and in js

```
$('#mainPlayer').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, {
                autoPlay:false, 
                description:description,
                jPlayer:{
                    swfPath:'path where jPlayer.swf is' //You need to override the default swf path any time the directory structure changes
                }
            });
```

It's easy, I have now good looking player. But I want to add some action on it's play-button. (I want to make an ability to play from server and from soundcloud).
Here is code of div with play button of player:

```
<div class="play jp-play" style="display: block;"></div>
```

So then I do this after `$(document).ready()` of course

```
.on('click','.jp-play',function(){
    alert("Works");
});
```

And after click on play button music plays but there is no alert. How can I override it's default action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it:

```
$(document).on($.jPlayer.event.play, function(e){
    console.log("play!");
    alert("Works");
});
```

This uses the jPlayer event `play`.

Other supported event types are described here: http://jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-event-type

Full example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/x4zua2d1/)

Comment: great, I'll just test your answer.

Comment: Ok, and how can I prevent music from playing then? There is an alert but music is still playing and e.preventDefault() doesn't works.

Comment: If you need to completely disable any click actions for the play button, just do ```.off('click')``` for it. See the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dekkard/x4zua2d1/